# BeautifulSoup extract URL from HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract `title` ( "Airmeet Invite Email" ) & `srcset` URLs from following HTML using `bs4`

[image]

I tried following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.mailmodo.com/email-templates/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="__next")
grid = results.find_all("img", class_="alt")
print(grid)
```

But I am unable to get the the title & url.

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select it more specific and and extract the attribute values with `.get()`:

```
for e in soup.select('.card-body img[loading="lazy"]'):
    print(e.get('alt') , e.get('srcset'))
```

Output

```
Airmeet Invite Email https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=640 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=750 750w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=828 828w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1080 1080w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1200 1200w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1920 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=2048 2048w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1678876198/strapi/airmeet_event_invite_51ce8dd7e1.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=3840 3840w
Mother's Day Sale Email Template https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=640 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=750 750w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=828 828w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1080 1080w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1200 1200w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1920 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=2048 2048w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680470111/strapi/mothers_day_sale_email_1187fdd7ae.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=3840 3840w
Easter Day Email Template https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=640 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=750 750w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=828 828w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1080 1080w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1200 1200w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1920 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=2048 2048w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1680874983/strapi/easter_day_email_2c8358d3db.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=3840 3840w
Teaser Email Template https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=640 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=750 750w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=828 828w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1080 1080w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1200 1200w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1920 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=2048 2048w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679118418/strapi/teaser_email_template_1_36b9466598.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=3840 3840w
Newsletter Welcome Email Template https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=640 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=750 750w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=828 828w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1080 1080w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1200 1200w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=1920 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=2048 2048w, https://res.cloudinary.com/mailmodo/image/upload/f_webp,q_10/v1679231780/strapi/welcome_email_template_bf85d44531.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=3840 3840w
...
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `img[loading="lazy"]` does in `select()` ?

Comment: It is a [css selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for the attribute of the element that holds your information and this one is specific for the element and excludes all the others that do not hold this attribute.